# Let me see my own deleted comments and be able to undelete them

Tags: feature-request, comments, deleted-comments

Use case: sometimes I comment on a question. Then I decide to delete it. After let's say 2 minutes the user that posted the question answers my comment but my comment is long gone! His reply to my comment is out of context now because no one can see what that comment is referring to (my deleted comment).

If ***I chose to delete*** the comment it could be hidden but stay there allowing me to bring it back. This can be done with deleted answers right now where I can undelete it if I want.

Comment: Comments are second-rate citizens; just re-post the comment.

Comment: @MartijnPieters If I repost it will be out of context too...

Comment: While comments **are** second-rate citizens that doesn't mean they aren't citizens at all. I would judge this on its merits and only declined it under "second-rate citizens" if it proves to require too much developer time

Comment: Why did you delete the comment in the first place?

Comment: @user689 I have done that before: "Write something long and complicated", realise I was wrong, delete it, then realise actually I wasn't wrong and have to retype the damn thing out again

Comment: @user689 because I thought that what I had asked in the comment had already been answered in the question itself. Then I realized it had not been answered in the question... :)

Comment: Its worth noting that comments are already only hidden, just very hidden (moderators can already retrieve them if they really want). So this wouldn't be that huge a change

Comment: perhaps the undelete feature should be time limited to prevent abuse.

Comment: @RichardTingle yep... I thought about that too - I had a feeling this was how it's currently implemented.

Comment: @Jan I'm not sure how someone could abuse such feature!

Comment: @user689 1:"I think we should do A -- suggester"; 2:"Wait no, better do B -- suugester"; [suggester swiftly deletes #2]; [someday later]3:"@suggester: That would be a bad idea, and the reason should be obvious. Too bad we can't downvote comments."; [suggester makes sure responder is gone, then undeletes #2]